# Accesing instance ip in LAN of openstack

Tags: openstack, devstack

I have installed Devstack in my ubuntu machine and im able to to run the instance of an ubuntu image .. the instance ip which gets assigned automatically (i.e) private ip and floating ip they are not working in other machines in LAN , but they are working in the same machine .. working in the sense showing default apache page as "It works" as i have installed LAMP server in Instance OS . How can access instance IP in other machines connected Locally i.e in the same network

Answer (score 2):

You should enable arp proxy and ip forwarding:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth0/proxy_arp
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

See more details at:
http://barakme.tumblr.com/post/70895539608/openstack-in-a-box-setting-up-devstack-havana-on-your

Comment: I ll check it out and get back . Thanks

Comment: just opened your site i think you are the man i needed badly :P, i have lots of queries for you.

Comment: I did everything same according to the link. But does not work, even the instance OS is not connecting to the internet forget about LAN access.Previously i used to get net in the instance OS.